# sorting a field in a access 2003 report field by a specific value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to figure out if there is any vba way of sorting a report field in access 2003. I have this field that contains three different values " Estimated date", "Needs date" and "Date in"; what i need is for the field to be sorted first from A-Z and then by Date. If anyone knows how to do this in either VBA or access2003 please let me know I'm fairly new to access and vba so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an Access report, use the report Group and Sort option to define your sort order.  That option over-rides any sort order established by the `ORDER BY` clause in the report's record source query.

I don't recall exactly where that option is found in the Access 2003 user interface, but suspect you can track it down.  Meanwhile be aware that Microsoft will discontinue support for Office 2003 in April 2014.

Here is a screenshot from Access 2007 which shows where the option is located on the ribbon interface.

[image: Report Group & Sort option]

Comment: Thanks i'll keep that in mind for the next time i run into a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

Yes, go to the queries tab and create a new query based on your table and sort on those fields.  Then modify your report to read data from the query and not directly from the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot it does exactly what i needed it to do  @Knuckle-Dragger